# DNS configuration to distribute traffic to multiple host on google cloud

Tags: dns, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform

We have 2 servers hosting a particular service on google cloud. How to do a simple round-robin DNS configuration to distribute the load?

Comment: did you try standard load balancer? https://console.developers.google.com/project/%PROJECT-ID%/loadbalancing/http/list

Comment: I have created a zone with type A record having multiple host IP. but on resolving the abc.com, it is returning third ip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-dns-discuss/JDp5ZCVclJ4) Google Cloud DNS does not support round-robin.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up DNS round robin with Cloud DNS simply by adding more than one IP address to your DNS record.

You might want to look into [Google Compute Engine's Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/) options. This will allow you to have one IP address that sends traffic to your two servers. This has a few advantages, including that you can configure it to automatically stop sending traffic to an instance if it fails a health check.

Comment: was trying to find out is there a way to get 2 nodes bare 50% load just by adding some configurations (without spending any penny on it)