# Equivalent like AWS Route53 service in GCP (cloud dns?)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

With AWS `Route53` I can setup an URL that assigns 50% traffic to one URL and the other URL, which points to different versions of the service. Is there sth similar in GCP (cloud dns)?

The setup looks like the following

```
                                50%    
100% traffic  ->  service.com   ->    serviceA.com (version-featureRF)
                                50%
                                ->    serviceB.com (version-featureCNN)
```

Update:
I have a look at
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32617722/3952994, but it doesn't explain how to set it up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DNS configuration to distribute traffic to multiple host on google cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825063/dns-configuration-to-distribute-traffic-to-multiple-host-on-google-cloud)

Comment: It implicitly mentions a doc: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/l7-internal/traffic-management. I'm still looking into how to configure

Answer (score -1):

From Cloud DNS is not possible to setup the configuration mentioned as is possible with AWS Route 53.

To balance the load between different services you can use [Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/load-balancing-overview).